# ViewPager is working but manual clicking on different tab fails

Tags: android-studio, android-viewpager

I am trying to implement ViewPager in my project which had been implemented successfully but, when I click manually on the Signup tab, then it's not responding anything but sliding is working fine. Where shall I put onClickListener and how I am not getting.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Login"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Signup"));

        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

        final LoginAdapter adapter = new LoginAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this, tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setTranslationY(300);

    }
}
```

```
public class LoginAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private Context context;
    int totalTabs;

    public LoginAdapter(FragmentManager fa, Context context, int totalTabs) {
        super(fa);
        this.context = context;
        this.totalTabs = totalTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return totalTabs;
    }

    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                LoginTabFragment loginTabFragment = new LoginTabFragment();
                return loginTabFragment;
            case 1:
                SignupTabFragment signupTabFragment = new SignupTabFragment();
                return signupTabFragment;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Only you need to set `addOnTabSelectedListener()` into your tabLayout and set the current item in `onTabSelected()` by using `viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());`.

```
 tableLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```